# Unable to locate the local module in python

Tags: python

[image]

I am trying to import get_profile_url from tools module in the tools folder , but it says that `No module named 'tools'` . I dont know why this is happening because even the vscode's ai can detect the packages when I am importing it  at line 4 . I am using venv as virtual environment and dont know whether its because of that.

Comment: How would you expect Python to be able to find that?  It doesn't know anything about your project, and it isn't going to searching up through the directory tree.  You can add `import os, sys` / `sys.path.append( os.path.abspath( os.path.dirname('__file__')+'/..'))` to have the directory above this script added to the path.

Comment: it's related to reach top level package. You should check this https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/modules.html#packages

Answer (score 0):

Try to put `.tools.tools` or `..tools.tools`

Comment: still error: ImportError: attempted relative import beyond top-level package

Comment: @GauravBahuguna I usually use Django and using `from tools import tools` would work fine. However, there is a set of criteria that will make your program recognize such a folder as a module. The `__init__.py` file could be one of these. Try to create an empty folder with that name and see what happens.